# Add custom fields to cases

Tags: custom-fields, civicase

Have managed to add custom fields to contacts, and have tried to do the same for cases. The option seems to be there, but they do not show up on the page for creating a new case.

[image]

I can add custom fields to activities within cases, but I would like them for the overall case itself.

Is there any extension to achieve this/ is there some setting I am missing?
Thanks.

Comment: I have tried this on the civicrm demo https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/ and the custom field will show up. The only different I can see is that I am  using shoreditch and using version 5.10

Answer (score 2):

You need to have selected a case type before the custom fields will appear.